# Inequality Proof (Shannon's)

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

I'm required to prove that $(\frac{A-B-C+2}{3}\cdot \log_2(\frac{2(A-B-C+2)}{A-B-C+D-E-F+4})+(\frac{B+C-A+1}{3})\cdot log_2(\frac{2(B+C-A+1)}{B+C-A+E+F-D+2}) )\geq0$

given that $0\leq A,B,C,D,E,F\leq 1$.

Does anyone have any idea how to prove it? Thanks in advance.

*I'm given an idea of Shannon's inequality.

Answer (score 2):

If you denote:
$$u_1=\frac{A-B-C+2}3\ \textrm{and}\ u_2=\frac{B+C-A+1}3$$
and
$$v_1=\frac{A-B-C+D-E-F+4}6\ \textrm{and}\ v_2=\frac{B+C-A+E+F-D+2}6.$$
You can verify that $0\leq u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2\leq 1$ and $u_1+u_2=v_1+v_2=1$.

Therefore you can consider $(u_1,u_2)$ and $(v_1,v_2)$ as two probability distributions. The quantity you wrote is the Kullback divergence of these distributions. And a Kullback divergence is always non negative. Your inequality is just
$$D_{KL}\left((u_1,u_2)||(v_1,v_2)\right)\geq 0.$$